For Neoplatonists is motion a process that can only take place in temporal settings?
In Proposition 2 of the Elements of Theology, Proclus writes that everything that participates in unity is simultaneously one and not-one. Further down, he claims that it has unity as an effect and had to go through a process of unification. My question is whether that process, this motion from potentiality to actuality—or for that matter, any other motion, motion understood in the Peripatetic sense—can take place in non-temporal settings for Neoplatonist thinkers, or if it is something that only pertains to the physical world.

Are you talking about “procession and return”, often translated as "emanation"? If so, then no, emanation is a timeless process for Neoplatonists. And Plotinus rejects the Peripatetic actualization of potentiality scheme altogether in Ennead II.5.

No, my problem lies in understanding where a thing which is distinct from the ONE, by participation in the ONE, goes through a change so that it becomes a unified manifold. Where does this process/change exactly take place in the sensible world , in the realm of Ideas or somewhere completely different?, and then if this change should take place in a non-temporal realm my follow up question would be -  is change not confined to temporality only in this  specific case of unification or is it   generally possible for change to occur in the absence of temporality.

See Majumdar, Plotinus on the Appearance of Time:"The Neoplatonist refutes Aristotle’s account of time as ‘number [or measure] of motion’... For Plotinus, time cannot be described by property or quantifying measure of the corporeals; time is associated with the intelligible life of the soul and not the physical or perceptible change. Plotinus defines eternity as the timeless life of Intellect." Neoplatonists are the heirs of Parmenides - change is an illusion. "Going through a process" is only a metaphorical description of what eternally is.

Thank you for the clarifying answer, which also reminds me to finally start reading about the philosophy of time. Have a nice day.
